# Errors when running Liferay through Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-7.1

I'm currently going through the liferay back-end development course and I'm trying to run the server however this is what shows up in the console.

2-Oct-2019 11:12:29.376 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 189635 ms

2019-10-22 11:12:35.625 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-2][JSONWebServiceServiceAction:97] Access denied to com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.service.KaleoDefinitionService#getKaleoDefinitions

I've already investigated to see what the Access denied has popped up but I haven't found anything relevant for my issue.

If it's of any help, I've already changed the JRE to a JDK in the runtime environment and it's not changed anything as far as I'm aware.

I've loaded the workspace they've used and there are a couple of issues inside of it but the same errors show up in the video and it doesn't seem to affect how they proceeded.

Comment: Notice: Liferay University shows a Comments section, to the right of the videos. If you comment there, you'll reach the training team, who has all of the content, in exactly the chapter where this came up. On stackoverflow, few people will have the context and setup.

Comment: @OlafKock Good idea Olaf thank you!